# Minimum path on potential energy surface using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, path

I used Matplotlib to plot a 3D potential energy surface.
But, I also want to show a reaction path with the lowest potential barrier between the minima of a potential energy surface by arrows.

Can any one help me with this: this is the my code for the 3D surface:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
INPUT='input.txt'

from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.mlab import griddata
from matplotlib import cm
from pylab import *
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FormatStrFormatter


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

data = np.genfromtxt(INPUT)
x = data[:,0]
y = data[:,1]
z = data[:,2]

xi = np.linspace(min(x), max(x))
yi = np.linspace(min(y), max(y))

X, Y = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)
Z = griddata(x, y, z, xi, yi, interp='linear')

ax.contourf(X, Y, Z, 30, zdir='z', offset=-7, linewidth=0.2, cmap=cm.jet, antialiased=False, shade=True)
C = ax.contour(X, Y, Z, 30, colors='k', linewidths=0.2)
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.jet, linewidth=0, antialiased=False, shade=False)
fig.colorbar(surf)
ax.clabel(C, inline=1, fontsize=10)

ax.set_xlabel(r"$d$$_{3}$ ($\AA$)")
ax.set_ylabel(r"$d$$_{4}$ ($\AA$)")
ax.set_zlabel(r"$\Delta$$E$$_{e}$ (kcal/mol)")

plt.show()
```

I want a graph like the one below:

[3D surface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3yV3.jpg)

Source: http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja801727k